# How do I reset a bundle config build for the current user that I accidentally set?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I was having issues with `bundle install`, specifically the mysql2 gem. Some answer suggested changing the build config build. So, I executed this command

`bundle config build.mysql2 --use-system-libraries`.

How do I undo this? It does not fix my issue so I want to revert it. `bundle config` displays this:

```
build.mysql2
Set for your local app (/Users/{user}/workspace/{appname}/.bundle/config): "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
Set for the current user (/Users/{user}/.bundle/config): "--use-system-libraries"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

See the .bundle/config files mentioned in the bundle config output.  Edit these to remove the settings you don't need or delete them if you don't need them at all.

Comment: Side question: isn't there a way to comment out lines in `.bundle/config`? The usual `#` seems to just be interpreted as part of a parameter key. 

Comment: Here are the docs and I can't find any reference to comments: https://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html You could try `//`

Comment: Yeah, I'd looked thru the (limited) docs too. Just tried each of "//", "\\", and ";;". For each, running `bundle config` just complains something to the effect of:
"You have not configured a value for `;;bundle_build.mysql2`"

Comment: Well then! The ruby syntax for multi-line comments does seem to work! Adding two more lines to the file to surround the line(s) with `=begin` and `=end` at least results in `bundle config` no longer complaining about the contained lines.

Answer (score 5):

Use `bundle config unset`:

> Executing `bundle config unset <name>` will delete the configuration in both local and global sources.
>
> *ref:* [man bundle config](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html)

Your example:

```
bundle config unset build.mysql2 --global
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem, Now when I try to do rails c or rails s I get this error:

```
xxx@Mac-mini xxx % rails c                                   
<internal:/Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle (LoadError)
```

I have deleted the .bundle folder and tried unset and nothing, the error persists.